# facebook access token doesn't update for old users

Tags: facebook

I updated my FB app permission to have more permissions. When a new user logs in everything works fine. When an old user tries to login fb dialog opens up and asks him to confirm the new permissions BUT the access token doesn't contain the new permissions.

Would love to hear some ideas!!

Thanks

Comment: I think you're overlooking something. Maybe you're using an old token, like the initial token?

Comment: sounds reasonable but ehy don't I get the updated token from fb? how can I get the new one?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check which permissions the user have granted you and if the user haven't granted all permissions that you need that you have to request them from the user.

Comment: Thanks! But when I check this user permissions for this app on facebook profile I see he has the new permissions for this app. But still when I try to retrive the data from the access token it's not there. Only basic information.